# Do the current nations also have their own angels like the 70 from in the Torah?

Tags: history, gentiles, theology, malach-angel, chutz-laaretz

Do the current nations (in 2021) also each have their own angel, like the 70 nations mentioned in the Torah?

Comment: He seems to want to know that since there are more than 70 nations and originally there were only 70 with one angel each. Now that there are more than 70, are there also more angels. The correct answer seems to be that there cannot be more than 70 so some nations will have to group together.

Comment: I think "70" in Chazal's idiom means two things: (1) the specific number (69 + 1 = 35 * 2 = 70), and (2) many. The second usage coming from this, the number of nations named in Bereishis 10 and the number of Israelites who went to Egypt. 70 thus became the stereotypical "a lot". And thus I don't think there is a claim that there were numerically 70 angels. For example, the Qeini, whom today's Druze believe they descend from, come from Yisro (Qeini being one of his many names). Well after the original 70.